# openLDAP MySQL password type

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, openldap

stackoverflow,

Background:
I'm working on a codeigniter project and in the future I wish to have an openLDAP server use the same database tables to provide a LDAP SSO type of desktop OS.

Question: what format does openLDAP store passwords in the MySQL table, md5 sha1 etc, so I can write the codeigniter model to suit?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/906.html
http://osr600doc.sco.com/cgi-bin/man?mansearchword=slapd.conf&mansection=5
The  must be one of {SSHA}, {SHA}, {SMD5}, {MD5}, {CRYPT}, and {CLEARTEXT}.
The default is {SSHA}.